# How to change custom link of subpages from of localhost to website

Tags: customization, links

I've created website using localhost. So while adding custom link of subpages like contact us or about its taking url of localhost instead of website like localhost/priyanka/about-us/. So how to change the custom link to website.

Comment: you may need to visit `wp-admin >> settings >> permalinks`

Answer (score 0):

When you move the local site to a domain, you will need to do a search/replace to update all the URLs to your domain.

I use the "Better Search and Replace" plugin to do that, although there are others, and even SQL statements to do that. I've just found that the plugin is a bit easier.

Don't forget to change the two site URLs in the wp-options table when you move the site to the domain.